# How to stop a service from a service

Tags: android, android-service

I am using location listerner in a service, and i have overriden `onLocationChanged(Location)` method. Now i want that whenever this method is called for the first time, i want to stop the service. So please tell me how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`stopSelf`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopSelf%28%29) from the `onLocationChanged` method (assuming the Service itself implements that interface).